# open a new terminal, let it stay, and switch back to original terminal, run command

Tags: linux, shell-script, terminal

I want implement like this
at terminal A, open a new terminal B, run command in B, leave B runing, and back to terminal A, run other command.

I have following script, but not what I expected

```
#!/bin/bash
konsole -e 'sh -c "./tel"'
echo test
```

The problem is, `echo test` command won't run, until I close terminal B. 
terminal A output

> "failed to get the current screen resources
>   QXcbConnection: XCB error: 170 (Unknown), sequence: 170, resource id: 90, major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 20"

and wait for terminal B close. after I close terminal B, terminal A output "test".

Is there a way to solve the problem?

Comment: konsole -e 'sh -c "./tel"'&  add & at the end of first command
makes no difference.

Comment: what about running `sh -c "./tel && exit"`

Comment: Welcome on U&L! I cannot reproduce your issue using konsole 18.08.3, Plasma Desktop 5.14.4, bash 4.4.23. No error here. May you add details about your environment? Are you using some virtual desktop (VNC...)?

Comment: my konsole is 16.08.2. SUSE OS
could you run konsole -e 'sh -c "ls ; exec bash"' in your terminal, see what happen.
mine switch to terminal B, and terminal A is suspended.

Comment: Pierre-Alain TORET, won't work

Comment: Since you asked: running `konsole -e 'sh -c "ls; exec bash"'` in terminal A: terminal B opens, executes, and stays; terminal A doesn't show a prompt, accepts input, doesn't execute until terminal B is closed. Running `konsole -e 'sh -c "ls; exec bash"' &` (note the final `&`) in terminal A: terminal B opens, executes, and stays; terminal A shows a prompt, accepts input, executes without waiting terminal B to be closed. All this is expected. (Continue...)

Comment: (... Continued) As it stands, your question is a duplicate because you are not explaining how the linked answer is not working for you. You should edit you answer, or ask a new, clearly different one. Explaining in comments will not work. (Comments (as these from me) are not meant to stay and will likely be deleted).

Comment: @fra-san. thanks for reply. I read the "Run a command without making me wait" and tried using &, put terminal B in background. see my first comment. it won't work, make no difference with or with out &.